# Add new element in existing object

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I am using node.js.

I have to add new elements in the object before to send a response to client.

```
user.getMatch(req.user, function(err, match){

        for( k=0; k<match.length; k++){
            var userId = {
                id : match[k].match_id  
            };
            var user = new User(userId);
            console.log('k: ' + k);
            user.getUserInfo(function(err2, info){
                console.log('k here: ' + k);
                if(info){
                    match[k].foo = info[0].foo;
                }
            });
        }

        var response = {
                data    : match
            };
        res.json(response);
});
```

I want to add an element "foo" from user.getUserInfo to the object "match" that was returned by user.getMatch. And then send all the data as response to the client.

But it got an error because "k" inside of user.getUserInfo is not equal to the "k" outside.
I do not know why the both "k" are not equal.

And how will I send a response to the client after performing the loop.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: since javascript is asynchronous you will get random values for k. instead of using a for loop for this, you can make use of async module

Comment: @V31, why random? **k** will always be equals to **match.length** when callback is called.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems here:

First, k is not defined so the k you're using is actually a global variable which is not what you want. You need to define it as 'var k'.

Second, the callback function you're passing to `user.getUserInfo()` is (probably) executed at some unknown time in the future. At this point your loop `for (k ...` has already finished so the the `k` variable already has a new value since the value that it had when you called `user.getUserInfo()`. And here's the tricky part: the code inside your callback function will use k's most recent value. It will *not* use the value that k had when the function was created.

You can solve this by adding a parameter to your callback function and binding k to it using the `.bind` method:

```
user.getMatch(req.user, function(err, match){

  var k;
  for(k=0; k < match.length; k++){
    var userId = {
      id : match[k].match_id  
    };
    var user = new User(userId);
    console.log('k: ' + k);

    var callback = function(k, err2, info){
      console.log('k here: ' + k);
      if(info){
        match[k].foo = info[0].foo;

      }
    }.bind(null, k);
    user.getUserInfo(callback);
  }

  var response = {
    data: match
  };
  res.json(response);
});
```

Also, you'd be better off by using `.forEach` for iterating over an array:

```
user.getMatch(req.user, function(err, match){

  match.forEach(function(curr) {
    var userId = {
      id : curr.match_id  
    };
    var user = new User(userId);

    user.getUserInfo(function(err2, info){
      if(info){
        curr.foo = info[0].foo;
      }
    }
  });

  var response = {
    data: match
  };
  res.json(response);
});
```

Although [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can give you your current index in the iteration, this is no longer needed. simply use the `curr` value (which gives you the current element in the iteration).

Finally, I think the code here is likely to send the response before all `user.getUserInfo()` calls have been executed. To achieve that you need to know when all `user.getUserInfo()` have been completed. This can be achieved by adding a variable `numLeft` which is decremented each time we get a user info. when this variable reaches zero we know that all `getUserInfo()` have completed and it is therefore safe to send the response back.

```
user.getMatch(req.user, function(err, match) {

  var numLeft = match.length;

  match.forEach(function(curr) {
    var user = new User({
      id : curr.match_id  
    });

    user.getUserInfo(function(err2, info){
      if(info) {
        curr.foo = info[0].foo;
      }
      --numLeft;
      if (numLeft == 0)
        res.json({ data: match });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I guess it would be better to transfer **k** when **User** object is being constructed. Just add one new parameter, and an each object will be aware of the array index it is supposed to work with.

Comment: But I got another issue.. it sends a response to client before it adds the "foo" element. So in the response to client, it only sends the object from "match" without the "foo" element.

Comment: @user3094292 please see the last snippet in my reply (just added it) - it addresses this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Fishy and Itay Maman. I used both or your answer. Thanks for your great help. Cheers! But I don't know which one will I mark as accepted because both of you have great answers. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @user3094292 if the answer is fine, would be helpful if you accepted it or upvoted it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "k inside and outside" do you mean inside and outside ofuser.getUserInfo(function(err2, info){})?

I am not sure of your context however i can think of two things

1. Since the function "function(err2, info)" is a callback and is executed asynchronously the context/stack in which k is used within getUserInfo is completely different. So try to pass k while calling i.e.

   user.getUserInfo(function(err2, info, k){}). This should work
2. Try to declare k i.e var k in the closure that you want it to be used

Updating for another part of question

"But I got another issue.. it sends a response to client before it adds the "foo" element. So in the response to client, it only sends the object from "match" without the "foo" element."

That is again because ur code inside get user info gets executed asynchronously.
For this you need to keep a global flag or try to send the response from within getUserInfo
i.e.

```
var mathLen = match.length;
user.getUserInfo(function(err2, info,k,mathLen)

{
                console.log('k here: ' + k);
                if(info){
                    match[k].foo = info[0].foo;
                }
                if(k==mathLen)
                {
                 var response = {
                    data    : match
                };
            res.json(response);
                     }

            });
```

Comment: @user3094292 if the answer is fine, would be helpful if you accepted it or upvoted it!!!!